# Symfony2 OneToOne or what to choose?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, twig, one-to-one

I have 2 tables.

**Tasks**

ID |UserID

**TaskDone**

ID |TaskID|UserID

I want to output all Tasks from a specific user but ONLY if there is an entry in TaskDone with matching TaskID and UserID.

I tried this:

```
/**
 * @var TaskDone
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskDone")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaskDone")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="task_id")
 */
protected $task_done;
```

This thorws following exception:

> Missing value for primary key id on Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskDone

How can I fix it and how would look like the output in my TWIG ?

Comment: Not sure if this would sort anything but I'm pretty sure the join column should be the other way around like `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")`.

Comment: Now i get this exception: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.task_title AS task_title2, t0.task_description AS task_description3, t0.task_priority AS task_priority4, t0.task_type AS task_type5, t0.user AS user6, t0.task_id AS task_id7 FROM tasks t0':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.task_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Have you updated your database?

Comment: Yes, he added "task_id" to tasks table. But this is wrong, therefor is the "ID" in tasks.

Comment: It seems like Doctrine isn't supporting this. I will do it now on an other way. return true or false in the controller to the twig template if there is an entry. Then I work with if cases in Twig template. Thank you for your help